# Postgres error: syntax error at or near ","

Tags: node.js, postgresql

i'm try to find error from my code but i dont know what i wrong.
Can Anyone see some error on it?

```
const {Client} = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
user: 'me',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'printer',
password: '1234',
port: 5432,
});

client.connect(function(err){
if (err) throw err
console.log("Connected Successfuly");
console.log("****if you want to stop this service, press Ctrl + C****");

var datain ='{"filename" : "filetest01.pdf","printer" : "Microsoft Print to PDF","address" : "C:\\Users\\parun\\Desktop\\printer\\printerserver\\photo","date" : "2020-11-23T17:00:00.000Z","status" : 1}';
var sql = 'INSERT INTO print(filename, printer, address, date, status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

client.query(sql, [datain.filename, datain.printer, datain.address, datain.date, datain.status],(err, result) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.table(result.rows);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any additional output?

Comment: `datain` is a string so `datain.whatever` will only ever be `undefined`. Remove the single-quotes if you want an actual object

Comment: @richyen no, i only have pg

Comment: @Phil ok, now im try t edit follow your comment but it's dont work and send me back to same my error

Comment: Can you indicate which line and column the error is at? Its easier to just post the full error stack trace

Comment: @PaulRooney now i can fix error is successful, thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your sql

```js
var sql = 'INSERT INTO print(filename, printer, address, date, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)';
```